# images from ajax call onclick function

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I use ajax to call a script that loads a gallery of images.

```
<?php
$dirname = $_GET["dirname"];
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
echo "<img onclick='clicked()' src=$dirname/$curimg>\n";
};
}     
?>
```

and the function "clicked()" is in the head of the page that runs the ajax call. For some reason, I can't get the "onclick" to call the "clicked()" function in the head of the main page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Lets see the ajax code

Comment: Do not use this code. You're allowing a malicious user to scan ANY directory on your server they want to.

Comment: @Marc B: Is there a better way to do this then?

Comment: sanitize the hell out of the user-provided path, and FORCE it to be within a certain sub-tree of your filesystem only ,e.g. `scandir('/unchangeable/path/you/require/' . sanitize($_GET['dirname']))`, so there's no way a malicious user can "break" out of your jail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an extraneous semicolon in the function on the main page.